# Fortran: flexible array filtering

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fortran, mask

in **Fortran** we coded as the following:

```
!vectors w,q are of the same size
...
w = ...         !a vector of integers [0,...,n)
if (allocated(t)) deallocate(t);
allocate(t(count(w/=0)))
t = pack(q, w/=0)
m = count(t>0)
if (allocated(b)) deallocate(b)
allocate(b(m))
b = pack(t,t>0)
```

to translate a code in **Python**:

```
t = q[w!=0]
b = t[t>0]
```

not sure the Fortran implementation we did is correct. Note that it is part of a very big program and we are getting some annoying runtime errors, sometime even no message but crash...

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Try turning on as many diagnostic compiler options as possible.

Comment: Try: -O2  -fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fwhole-file  -fcheck=all  -std=f2008  -pedantic  -fbacktrace

Comment: please post (1) a (non-)working example, (2) what are the runtime errors telling you, (3) why do you think the errors are related to this part of the code.

Comment: This part looks OK. One can see how much will the Fortran 2008 automatic allocation make things easier.

Comment: @eriktous Well there is **no question mark**! "...not sure the Fortran implementation we did is correct..." Would you have a better implementation which not so complicated as our version?

Answer (score 2):

In F2003, declare t and b as allocatable vectors and write simply :

```
t = pack(q, w/=0)
b = pack(t,t>0)
```

This is already supported by several compilers like gfortran (GCC 4.6) of ifort (Intel compiler suite > 11.x)

Comment: In gfortran it doesn't actually work good. It is OK for allocatable scalars, but there are still issues for arrays even in gfortran 4.7. Also you loose portability. With Fortan many people target High Performance computers, which are likely to have older versions of compilers.

Comment: Vladimir F -- I think that's pretty unlikely; all the HPC centres I know keep their compilers and tools very up to date; and pack has been around since Fortran 90..

Comment: That's good having such simplicity(=efficiency) in F2003. We are on GCC4.5.2 now and it doesn't fail in compile but the output(t or b) is empty!